# what is the difference between getSession().save() vs. getHibernateTemplate().save()?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using `Dao` classes that subclasses `HibernateDaoSupport`.

I have seen examples which calls

```
getSession().save(instance)
```

as well as

```
getHibernateTemplate().save(instance)
```

what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getSession opens a new session

whereas the hibernatetemplate does a best effort to find an existing session/transaction.

Hibernate template is more effective way to database connection. for more info
[click here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)

Answer (score 0):

`HibernateTemplate` generally a helper class provided by spring hibernate support, to make it really convenient to get the Session & transactions and to commit the Transaction you need not to do it manually while in case of `getSession()` you need to manage transactions.